# Setting up automatic reboot?

Tags: reboot, automation

This may sound a bit lazy, but does anybody know of an app or a method that can automatically reboot one's phone? I sometimes forget to reboot it daily (I like keeping my OS fresh).

Answer (score 1):

If your device is rooted, [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can do that (there's a free trial available at their website for you to check first). While you don't need to boot your device daily (I don't boot it more often than once a month usually, if at all), I also thought about a weekly reboot on a device having problems otherwise (my old Wildfire started behaving oddly with calls after about 10 days uptime).

So here we go, assuming a weekly reboot at Monday morning 3am for a fresh week:

**Condition:**

- *Day → Day-of-week:* pick "Monday"
- *Time:* Set both, From and To time to 3am

**Task:**

- *Reboot*

I have to include a warning here from the [Tasker UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html) on Reboot:

> Unfortunately, this is not a 'clean' shutdown. Neither Android nor running applications are informed that the device is rebooting, so be prepared for possible data corruption.
>
> On the other hand, every other app that allows reboot does it the same way.

So this warning does not apply to *Tasker* alone, but obviously to all other solutions as well.