# How can I reboot without manually shutting down my phone?

Tags: reboot

I am using Philippines local brand Cherry Mobile Android One. There are times that I want to reboot my phone. Unfortunately, it doesn't have one, or does Android One phone have reboot options?

Right now I'm stuck on manually shutting it down using power button, then opening it again.

Comment: Well there are lots of question regarding rebooting phone - Check out this similar threads on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966486/reboot-the-phone-on-a-button-click

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505158/reboot-android-device-programmatically

Comment: @BrotskyTv it tooks about programming. Sorry, but is there a way to reboot my device without creating my own app? Or if possible a built in reboot function?

Answer (score 0):

1. `adb reboot` from a PC
2. `reboot` from a shell/terminal

For automating this, you could try Tasker or a similar app.  See [Setting up automatic reboot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46883/1465)